# Should I award my bounty if the best answer is not that good?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I placed a bounty on [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/62762/what-does-a-confused-creature-do-when-it-has-to-attack-the-nearest-creature) and it's coming to its end.

As it is there is no question that really answer my problem, even if one provides a beginning of an answer.

Should I award the bounty to this one or just let it wear out?

Comment: If you let it wear out, a half-value bounty will automatically be awarded, keep that in mind when letting it run out.

Answer (score 7):

I have a mix of suggestions for you in this scenario.

- Award the bounty to the answer most helpful to you or that you find most deserving.
- Ask a new question asking about resource expenditure during the confused state.

---

Bounties actually get awarded automatically (at **half value**) after they expire if there's an answer eligible for the automatic award. You can read about that in [the bounty FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/152515) under the heading "What is automatic awarding?".

Answers are eligible for automatic awarding if they were posted during the bounty period **and** meet one of these criteria:

- you accepted the answer during the bounty period, *or if you didn't do this...*
- it has a score of at least +2 and the bounty author didn't post it themselves. (In case of multiple answers, the one with the highest score is chosen; if two have equally higher score, the oldest is chosen.)

Currently that means [Wannabe Warlock's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/99649/1204) will receive half the bounty value (25 points) automatically when the bounty expires.

Since somebody is going to get it, you might as well award the full value to somebody.

---

I also recommend the following caution:

**Assume that nobody at all might actually read the bounty.** If you're lucky, they'll at least read the *reason* you chose: “The current answers do not contain enough detail.” They may not keep reading to actually read the message you wrote out (it's easy to miss). **Assume that most people will only see the point value of [+50] and try to provide a super awesome answer to the question.**

I say this because the information you requested — “how much resources the confused creature is supposed to spend, if any” — isn't actually requested in the question itself. It's a request for new detail. People will miss it.

In this scenario, you're asking for extra/deeper detail, and the best way for you to get it is **ask a new question entirely.** In that one, link back to this [What does a confused creature do when it has to "attack the nearest creature"?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/62762/what-does-a-confused-creature-do-when-it-has-to-attack-the-nearest-creature) and say you want to know to what extent the confused creature is meant to use up their own resources. If you hadn't posted the bounty yet I'd suggest editing into the question (it seems in line with what it's asking for), bolding it, then posting the bounty. Right now though I recommend asking a new question primarily because it will give you the best chance of learning what you want to learn, and it's distinct enough from the basics covered in that question to stand on its own as a non-duplicate.

Comment: I'll do that, but note that the reason I placed this bounty was that the new question I asked has been closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @AnneAunyme That's because it opens up by asking "what does this mean, do you use spells", etc, which this question was already covering. Instead, I recommend acknowledging what you've already learned: "Ok, so based on [this other question] you do use spells, and powers and feats and abilities are on the line to be used as well." And then ask your further point: "How much of expendable resources are you expected to use? Do you have pressure to use your best spells, or things that are limited like once/day abilities? Do you have pressure to use relevant consumables?" etc.

Comment: That highlights in what way it's clearly distinct, and doesn't invite people to cover again the ground of what you do. We already know what you do, you're interested in learning *how much you use up to do it*, so make it clear you're focusing on that.

Comment: The major difference between what I want and the question as answered is that I want rule citation, which the existing answer doesn't provide.

Comment: @AnneAunyme It's possible there *isn't* a rules citation available.

Comment: @HeyICanChan: indeed, but in that case I would expect an answer saying that clearly.

Comment: @AnneAunyme If you're asking only for rules citation, I am sorry to say you chose an incorrect bounty reason: you chose "improve details", but there is an "authoritative reference needed" bounty reason for scenarios where the explanation is fine but citation is missing. Your bounty message also doesn't merely request citation: it requests additional detail on resource expenditure with citation, which is appropriate for a new question.

Comment: Could Anne answer the question authoritatively and award the bounty to that answer?

Comment: @doppelgreener: the answers weren't fine either. They are better now, but still lack the minimum reference I am looking for.

Comment: @HeyICanChan: I don't have the answer to the question (as you said, it is possible there is none).

Comment: @HeyICanChan A bounty poster can award the bounty to their own answer, but they won't get the points back. They'll vanish.